# Fundamental Theorem of calculus and limits

Tags: calculus

For a certain value of c the limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^ce^{-2x}\int_{0}^x e^{2t}\sqrt{3t^2+1} dt$$

exists (is ﬁnite), and is not zero. Find c and evaluate the limit.

I rearranged and got
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_{0}^x e^{2t}\sqrt{3t^2+1} dt}{x^{-c}e^{2x}}$$

I then used LH rule and got 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{ \sqrt{3x^2+1}}{x^{-c}(\frac{-c}{x}+2)}$$
and then I'm stuck. Please help

Comment: $x^{-c}\left(\frac{-c}{x}\right) = -cx^{-c-1}$. Also, divide denominator and numerator by $x$, and note that any term with $1/x^n$-like dependency on $x$ will be negligible for large $x$ and positive $n$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: For which value of $x$ can you do that? This may serve as an intuitive rule of thumb, but this is by no way a rigorous argument.

Comment: @Roland: I have removed the hint (never deemed a complete solution), as the L'Hospital rule is more appropriate here. Anyway, you can base a rigorous demonstration on the approximation of the original function by another of the same order of magnitude. And decompose the integral in a constant part from $0$ to $x_0$, then a known approximation from $x_0$ to $x$. The integrand is asymptotically $e^{2t}\sqrt3t$, and so is the primitive.

Comment: @Arthur: I made a typo in the denominator before do your hints still apply

Comment: My hint still applies, just remember to also multiply your $2$ with $x^{-c}$ as you multiply out the parenthesis in the denominator. It is still, also, a good idea to divide above and below by $x$ so that the limit of the numerator is $\sqrt{3}$, as that forces the limit of the denominator to be some finite non-zero number in order for the limit of the whole fraction to be finitely non-zero (this is not _strictly_ necessary, but it really helps to get an understanding of how degrees interact with limits of fractions, and it makes it easier to not get an off-by-one error or similar)

Comment: @Arthur: How do you find c though

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the numerator is "like" $x$, the denominator is "like" $x^{-c-1}$...

Comment: i made a typo in the denominator before does your hint still apply